# Add keyword before and after cast() in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, select

I would like to add a keyword before and after each field value in Oracle.

For example if I am getting `123` as my `ID`, I would like to make it

> Test123Test

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
CAST("ID" as varchar(10))
FROM
TABLENAME;
```

I have tried add `+ "Test"` but it is giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`||`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) instead of `+` to concatenate strings in Oracle.

```
SELECT 'test' || CAST(ID as varchar(10)) || 'test'
FROM   TABLENAME
```

Note that I removed the `"` around `ID` too, since you most likely won't need them and they can cause problems when it unintended strictly matches column names.

Comment: What is `||`? Usually that means `OR` but that doesn't make sense here... basically it is saying Test or ID or Test? Please explain

Comment: It is the string concatenation operator of Oracle... See the documentation under `||` in my answer.

Comment: Great! Will accept answer when I can :) It is different in Visual Studio I guess because I never used this operator before

Comment: @user4244510: the `||` is the string concatenation operator that was defined in the SQL standard nearly 30 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried add + "Test" but it is giving me error.

Perhaps, `+` is used as concatenation in **SQL Server**. In **Oracle**, you could use the **CONCAT** function or the `||` operator.

The concat function is restricted to only two strings. You can have a look the concat function in the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm.

Let's see an example using the operator -

```
SELECT 'test' || to_char(id) || 'test' new_id
FROM   TABLENAME
```